# What is meant by $A\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ where $A$ is a torsion-free abelian group?

Tags: tensor-products

I'm not sure what is meant by,

$A\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ where $A$ is a torsion-free abelian group?

I would be helpful if someone can tell me why the tensor can be taken, as I only know the vector space definition.

Comment: Notice that in the vector space definition the inverses of the coefficients are not needed. This means that the same definition for vector spaces can be used for modules. $A$ can be seen as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module by taking $na:=a+a+\ldots+a$ ($n$ summands). The same is true for $\mathbb{Q}$ or any other abelian group.

Answer (score 2):

Any abelian group can be thought of as a module over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Of course $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$. So $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$, is just the localization of the module $A$ at the multiplicatively closed subset $\mathbb{Z}^{*}$. Does that help?

$\textbf{EDIT}$

So what does the localization of $A$ at $\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$ look like? The y are tuples $(a,r)$ with $a\in A$ and $r\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$ such that $r\neq 0$. $(a,n)$ and $(b,m)$ are equivalent in the localization if $ma-nb=0$. So we can identify each element of $A_{\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}}$ with a fraction of the form $\tfrac{a}{n}$ where $a\in A$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$. From here can you see the vector space structure? How would we scale by things in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I do not understand 'So A⊗ZQ, is just the localization of the module A at the multiplicatively closed subset Z∗'
Why can I conclude that A can be viewed as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space from this?

Comment: @user93826 $A$ is not a $\mathbb Q$-vector space here; it's only an abelian group, which is equivalent to being a $\mathbb Z$-module.  But the tensor product $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$ is a  $\mathbb Q$-vector space.  Multiplication of elements of $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$ by rational numbers is defined by setting $(a\otimes x)\cdot q=a\otimes(xq)$ and extending by additivity.