# Direct sum of Abelian Finitely generated groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

how are you?

I am trying to solve the next problem, but I dont even know exactly how to work with the definitions.

> Let $A$ be an abelian group which is finitely generated and such that $A \oplus A \cong A$. Prove that $A=0$. Give an example with a abelian group $A \neq 0$ such that $A \oplus A=A$.

Can someone help me to understand this statement and give me hints on how to solve it?

Comment: For the first part, use the structure theorem for finititely generated abelian groups. For the second part, try and take $A$ to be the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: HINT: if $d(G)$ denotes the minimum number of elements generating the abelian group $G$, then $d(G \oplus H)= d(G)+d(H)$.

Comment: Regarding the definition of this sum, is it the same as the direct product since I have just a finite number of terms??

Comment: @bttmbrcelo Yes: but what I wrote is a theorem, not a definition.

Comment: Yes, yes, I see. Thank you. Just one thing more: that 0, then, is the identity. OKay?

Comment: $0$ usually (in the context of abelian groups, when additive notation is used) denotes the trivial group.

Comment: @Crostul can you give me a link to the proof of that formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \oplus A \cong A$ implies $\operatorname{tor} A \oplus \operatorname{tor} A \cong \operatorname{tor} A$ and so $\operatorname{tor} A=0$, that is, $A$ is torsion-free.

Let $V=A\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$. Then $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $V \oplus V \cong V$. The only way is $V=0$.

For the second part, take $A=\mathbb{Z}^{\infty}=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512372/what-is-meant-by-a-otimes-mathbbq-where-a-is-a-torsion-free-abelian-group.